# Gulp serve error : Cannot find module '@microsoft/sp-build-web'

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

I am working on the SharePoint Framework Tutorial 1 for the Hello World Web Part. When running the build command **gulp serve** to build and preview the webpart I get the following error "**Cannot find module '@microsoft/sp-build-web'**".

Here are the details:

> `PS C:\src\spfm\helloworld-webpart> gulp serve module.js:327
>       throw err;
>       ^ Error: Cannot find module '@microsoft/sp-build-web'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>       at Object.<anonymous> (C:\src\spfm\helloworld-webpart\gulpfile.js:4:15)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:353:17)`

I've checked the project structure and under the **node_modules/@microsoft** path I can see the following folders but not **sp-build-web**

- sp-client-base
- sp-client-preview
- sp=modules-interface
- sp-webpart-workbench

Any ideas?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44402/discussion-on-question-by-dimitrie-agafitei-gulp-serve-error-cannot-find-modul).

Comment: Thanks @https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/43514/amay-kulkarni your solution solved my issue.

Answer (score 6):

Update to node package manager (npm) 3 using `npm -g install npm@next` 
and your path length issues should go away

This is because the LTS version of node ships with npm v2.x whereas npm 3.x has better package handling and doesn't create such deeply nested folders.

Comment: Great Also used **npm cache** and then **npm i** . It worked perfect!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when I couldn't install Phantom due to an error on their server. I fixed the issue by rerunning `npm i` in the command line.

Comment: It did the trick only had to run npm cache clean before npm i

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party, but the only thing that worked for was:

```
npm install @microsoft/sp-build-web@1.6.0
```

But I still get other errors and gulp serve still won't run so I give up - customizing classic was so much quicker and easier...

Comment: Thanks that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

My corporate environment doesn't use a proxy as I couldn't be able to locate in internet explorer settings. But there are firewalls which blocks everything. I used following command and '@microsoft/sp-build-web' error was resolved.

Command: npm install --save-dev '@microsoft/sp-build-web'

I followed the web and got many resolutions but putting the above worked. Hope this helps somebody.

Thanks

Comment: Using      "npm install --save-dev"         resolved the issue