# Unable generate default web part with SFx with Yeomen

Tags: spfx-tooling

I was following
https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment on Windows 10 machine.
I opened command prompt window in Admin mode.
installing NodeJS, npm and then 
npm install -g yo gulp
and npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint 
completed successfully.

On the next page, https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part
I created new folders (

```
md helloworld-webpart
```

, then

```
cd helloworld-webpart
```

)
and started

```
yo @microsoft/sharepoint
```

After running for minutes, I've got

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@* (node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-webpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! path E:\Demos\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\.staging\@types\lodash-16ec5ab8
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'E:\Demos\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\.staging\@types\lodash-16ec5ab8' -> 'E:\Demos\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\@types\lodash'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'E:\Demos\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\.staging\@types\lodash-16ec5ab8' -> 'E:\Demos\helloworld-webpart\node_modules\@types\lodash'
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'E:\\Demos\\helloworld-webpart\\node_modules\\.staging\\@types\\lodash-16ec5ab8',
npm ERR!   dest: 'E:\\Demos\\helloworld-webpart\\node_modules\\@types\\lodash',
npm ERR!   parent: 'helloworld-webpart' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     E:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-03-31T18_31_21_102Z-debug.log
```

I tried a couple of times and got the same result.

npm -v 
3.10.10
Node -v 
v7.5.0

I found similar questions:
[Gulp serve error : Cannot find module '@microsoft/sp-build-web'](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191289/gulp-serve-error-cannot-find-module-microsoft-sp-build-web)
and 
[Yeoman generator for WebPart can't find Github repo #spfx #spfx-webparts #spfx-tooling](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201743/yeoman-generator-for-webpart-cant-find-github-repo-spfx-spfx-webparts-spfx-t)
but none of the suggestions helped.

Comment: Andrew,
I tried both in Admin and regular prompt with no difference.
I did not try to run LTS v6. Many new developers won't be familiar how to use multiple versions of NodeJS.
I know that you cover this in your course https://www.voitanos.io/products/mastering-the-sharepoint-framework-starter/categories/235478.
I'm prividing my own answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped me I found here: 
http://ericoverfield.com/update-sharepoint-framework-yeoman-generator/
In particular, the line:

npm update -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@latest

After the update, I see

> npm list -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint
>   `-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.0.2

The issue has gone. Now, I'm able to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of some people having some trouble with the Node v7... have you tried it on an LTS version like v6?

Also, are you running this from an administrative command prompt? I see that in the error above... worth investigating...